# Using one set of unit tests on many different files in Racket

Tags: unit-testing, racket

I'm looking for advice on how to structure my Racket programs. Currently, I have about 5 different versions of the program and each program has the same unit tests (RackUnit) just added to the end of each file. This is hard to maintain.

What I want to do is pull out the tests into a separate file and ask RackUnit to run the tests once for each program. But I'm not sure how to do that. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, perhaps we can do something highly dynamic by using Racket's [reflection system](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/reflection.html).

Let's say, for example, that we're making sure that a set of modules all provide a function `f` that appears to be a monotonically increasing function.  How might we write a framework of testing a collection of implementations with the same battery of tests?

We can write a harness that:

- constructs a module that `requires` an implementing module in question, and
- runs the set of tests on it.

The code might look something like this:

```
(define (test-module-with-monotonic-f module-path-name)
  (define ns (make-base-namespace))
  (printf "testing ~s\n" module-path-name)
  (eval `(begin (module a-test-module racket/base
                  (require rackunit
                           (file ,(path->string module-path-name)))
                  (check-true (> (f 1) (f 0))
                              (format "~a fails to provide monotonic f" ,module-path-name))
                  (check-true (> (f 3) (f 2))
                              (format "~a fails to provide monotonic f" ,module-path-name)))
                (require 'a-test-module))
        ns))
```

which does the construction of the testing module, and runs it using a dynamic `eval`.  `eval` is usually considered evil, but in this particular situation, I think it's an appropriate tool.

Once we have this helper, we can run it on a collection of files, say in an `impls` subdirectory:

```
(for ([mod-name (in-directory "impls")]
      #:when (equal? (filename-extension mod-name) #"rkt"))
  (test-module-with-monotonic-f mod-name))
```

You can try the [complete running example (https://github.com/dyoo/monotonic-f-example)](https://github.com/dyoo/monotonic-f-example) to see all the pieces.

(It should be clear that the tests above are woefully insufficient, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how robust this is, but here is a solution using a hygiene-breaking macro. (Danny is smarter than me though :) so maybe you'll want to follow his advice.)

File `f1.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(define (f x) (displayln "f1's f") (+ x 1))
(define (g x) (displayln "f1's g") (+ x 2))
(require "f-tests.rkt")
(tests)
```

File `f2.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(define (f x) (displayln "f2's f") (+ 1 x))
(define (g x) (displayln "f2's g") (+ 2 x))
(require "f-tests.rkt")
(tests)
```

File `f-tests.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(provide tests)
(define-syntax (tests stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_)
     (datum->syntax 
      stx
      '(begin
         (require rackunit)
         (check-equal? (f 10) 11)
         (check-equal? (g 20) 22)))]))
```

The [`datum->syntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html?q=syntax-%3Edatum#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._datum-~3esyntax%29%29) says that the `tests` macro should use the identifiers in the context of `stx`, ie where the macro is *invoked* (normally, the macro will use the identifiers at the time the macro is *defined*). Running either file `f1.rkt` or `f2.rkt` will run the tests. (The prints are just to prove that the correct function is being called.)